# How to open a new activity after logging into Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I was following a tutorial on this exact question but the method used (`Facebooksdk.sdkInitialize`) appears to be deprecated. So now I'm unsure how to open a new activity after login. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

What's the most simple way to open a new activity after login?

Comment: put your login call back method too

Comment: Don't have one, this is all the code I have.

Comment: ok, then try [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,login button have callbacks and onSuccess you can move to next activity....

//Declare this on Top

```
CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    LoginButton loginButton;
```

//in onCreate

```
 mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);

//OPEN ACTIVITY FROM HERE
          startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }
    });
```

//and put this method on your activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Just try this code it will work fine for you just make sure your Facebook APi is correct and your have done manifest entry,too.if you find it useful make it as a true, thanks.

Comment: I'll try this soon, but can you tell me how each part of this code is working?